# Remove lines exhibiting a unique STRING

Tags: awk, sed

I have a text file with approx. 12 millions of lines, each composed of 4 fields (column 1, 2, 3 and 4)

Most lines have a unique STRING in column 2 and I would like to remove them. The entire text file is SORTED according column 2 (smaller to greater); lines with identical STRING in column 2 are always consecutive.

Spread in the text file, I regularly have 2, 3, 4 or 5 consecutive lines with the same STRING in column 2. These are the lines that I would like to keep in the final text file:

```
column1 column2 column3 column4  
WT 1 ILS G  
WT 2 DSG E          
WT 3 WYT S 
. . . .  
WT 106  AAA X  
WT 106  BBB Y  
. . . .  
WT 2704 CCC X  
WT 2704 DDD Y 
WT 2704 EEE X  
. . . .  
WT 87520 FFF X  
WT 87520 GGG X  
WT 87520 HHH X  
WT 87520 III Y  
. . . .
```

What I would I like to achieve:

```
column1 column2 column3 column4  
WT 106  AAA X  
WT 106  BBB Y  
WT 2704 CCC X  
WT 2704 DDD Y 
WT 2704 EEE X  
WT 87520 FFF X  
WT 87520 GGG X  
WT 87520 HHH X  
WT 87520 III Y
```

Thanks in advance for your time and help.
Best,

Laurent

Comment: Is your text file already sorted by column 2 or are the lines with the same value for column 2 **always** consecutive?   If not, does it matter if the file is sorted (i.e. do you care about the order of the output?)   If the output order does matter (and if it's not possible to re-sort it into the order you want), it will require significantly more RAM (because you'll need enough to hold the 12 million files in memory) and be significantly slower than if the output order doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk 'FNR==1 {print; next} $2==p2 {print p $0; p=""; next} {p=$0 ORS; p2=$2}' file
```

If column 2 matches: print previous line and current line, empty the variable that held the previous line, and go to the next line.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion that worked. Thanks for your time and for sharing your knowledge. It helped me. Best.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `uniq -D` to print duplicate lines, but it can only skip fields from the left. Therefore, we need to apply `rev` to reverse each line, then use `uniq`, and finally use `rev` again to reverse the lines back.

```
rev file | uniq -f2 -D | rev
```

Answer (score 1):

Grouping input data problems are handled using the module `itertools` and the method `groupby`. It takes two arguments: an iterator, in our case the input file handle. And a  key specifying function ( in our case an anonymous function)

```
python3 -c 'import sys
from itertools import groupby
ifile,prntHdr = sys.argv[1],False
with open(ifile) as f:
  for k,igrp in groupby(f, lambda x: x.split()[1]):
    G = list(igrp)
    if not prntHdr or len(G) > 1:
      print(*G,sep="",end="")
      prntHdr = True
' file
```

---

```
perl -nae '
  push @A, $_;
  if ($prev ne $F[1] || $.==1) {
    print(splice(@A,0,@A-(@A>2?1:$.==1?0:@A)));
    shift @A if @A>1;
    $prev = $F[1];
  }
  END { print @A if @A>1; }
' file
```

---

```
sed -Ee '1b
  $!N
  /^\S+\s+(\S+)\s.*\n\S+\s+\1\s/{
    P;h;D  
  }
  x
    /./{x;P;x;z;}
  x
  D
' file
```